# How to redirect end-user to another web page using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to redirect the end-user on checking/unchecking checkboxes ? How, please ?

I've tried to redirect him using `get method` with this code

HTML

```
<form><input type="checkbox" name="fixee" value="true" style="margin-left:40px;margin-right:3px;" /><input type="checkbox" name="nonFixee" value="true" style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:3px;" /></form>
```

jQuery

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
    if ($("input[name='fixee']").prop('checked') && $("input[name='nonFixee']").prop('checked')) {
        alert('2');
    }
    else if ($("input[name='fixee']").prop('checked') && $("input[name='nonFixee']").prop('checked')) {
        alert('3');
    }
    else{
        alert('1');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eKa8S/9/

I'm coding this in Visual Studio the `~` means the root folder of the project.

Any brilliant idea, please ?

Comment: Have you tried window.location.href?

Comment: Here is a stack overflow post which might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript

Comment: @markpsmith, can you show me please how this works ?

Comment: Check these links .It may help you.

[How can I make a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript?][1]


[How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `window.location = "~/Alertes/Index?fixee=true&nonFixee=true"`

Answer (score 0):

Your example rworked to do the get:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
    if ($("input[name='fixee']").attr("checked") && !$("input[name='nonFixee']").attr("checked")) {
        window.location = "~/Alertes/Index?fixee=true&nonFixee=false";
    }
    else if (!$("input[name='fixee']").attr("checked") && $("input[name='nonFixee']").attr("checked")) {
        window.location = "~/Alertes/Index?fixee=false&nonFixee=true";
    }
    else {
        window.location = "~/Alertes/Index?fixee=true&nonFixee=true";
    }
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eKa8S/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
    if ($("input[name='fixee']").prop('checked') && $("input[name='nonFixee']").prop('checked')) {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action1", "Controller")'
    }
    else if ($("input[name='fixee']").prop('checked') && $("input[name='nonFixee']").prop('checked')) {
         window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action2", "Controller")'
    }
    else{
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action3", "Controller")'
    }
});
```